# Unable to eliminate stop words using nltk from a sequence of words

Tags: python, nltk, stop-words

I have a sequence of words and I want to eliminate all the stop words from it using nltk. The code snippet for the same is given below:

```
#tokensgenerated has the sequence of words
for word in tokensgenerated:
    if(word not in nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')):
          #do something with the word
```

However,
I am getting a run time error.

> " except LookupError: raise e "

I have imported nltk.

Anything I am missing?

Comment: Could you provide the full error traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First download and ensure that your `stopwords` are already downloaded, see http://www.nltk.org/data:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> packages = ['stopwords']
>>> downloader.download(packages)
>>>
>>> stop = stopwords.words('english')
>>> sent = 'this is a foobar sentence'.split()
>>> [word for word in sent if word not in stop]
['foobar', 'sentence']
```

Comment: Hi. Yes. I had realized that I had not downloaded stopwords. Thanks :)